# The convergence of $\sum \pm a_n$ with random signs

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $\left(a_n\right)$ is a sequence of real numbers and that $\left(\varepsilon_n\right)$ is a sequence of IID RVs with
$$P\left(\varepsilon_n = \pm 1\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

According to Williams (Probability with Martingales (1991), Section 12.3 "Random signs", pp. 113-114), the results of Section 12.2 show that

i. $\sum \varepsilon_n a_n$ converges (a.s.) if and only if $\sum a_n^2 < \infty$, and that

ii. $\sum \varepsilon_n a_n$ (a.s.) oscillates infinitely if $\sum a_n^2 = \infty$

People have asked about (ii.) in [Infinite oscillation of random signs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664932/infinite-oscillation-of-random-signs), but I do not understand the ($\Rightarrow$) part in (i.). In Theorem 12.2(b), it is required that $(X_k)$ are bounded by some constant $K$. However, $\varepsilon_n a_n$ is not necessarily bounded, so why is it true that $\sum a_n^2 < \infty$?

(Results of Section 12.2)
**Theorem 12.2 (Sums of zero-mean independent variables in $\mathcal{L}^2$, pp. 112-113)**. Suppose that $\left(X_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that, for every $k$,
$$E\left(X_k\right) = 0,\ \sigma_k^2 := \mathrm{Var}\left(X_k\right) < \infty$$

a. Then
$$\left(\sum \sigma_k^2 < \infty\right)\ \textrm{implies that }\left(\sum X_k\ \textrm{converges a.s.}\right)$$

b. If the variables $\left(X_k\right)$ are bounded by some constant $K$ in $\left[0,\infty\right)$ in that $\left|X_k\left(\omega\right)\right| \leq K$, $\forall k, \forall \omega$, then

$$\left(\sum X_k\ \textrm{converges, a.s.}\right)\ \textrm{implies that }\left(\sum \sigma_k^2 < \infty\right)$$

**Notes to the theorem**

1. The Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law implies that
   $$P\left(\sum X_k\ \mathrm{converges}\right) = 0\ \mathrm{or}\ 1$$
2. The proof of part b given in the book shows in fact that if $\left(X_k\right)$ is a sequence of independent zero-mean RVs uniformly bounded by some constant $K$, then
   $$\left(P\left\{\textrm{partial sums of }\sum X_k\ \textrm{are bounded}\right\} > 0\right) \implies \left(\sum X_k\ \textrm{converges a.s.}\right)$$

Comment: Well, you can conclude that if $\sum \epsilon_k a_k$ converges almost surely, then $a_k$ must (surely) converge to 0, which means we do indeed have $|a_k\epsilon_k| = |a_k| \leq K$ for all $k$, for some constant $K$ (so then you can apply the "part b of Theorem 12.2").

Comment: @Michael You're right. I'm missing the point that $a_n$ is not random. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah.  The partial sums change by exactly $|a_k|$ with each additional term (either forward or backward depending on $\epsilon_k$), so if $a_k$ does not  tend to zero then the partial sums cannot converge.