# Show that $\sum \pm X_n<\infty$ a.s. implies $\sum X_n^2<\infty$ a.s.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ are arbitrary random variables such that $\sum \pm X_n$ converges almost surely for all choices $\pm1$. Show that $\sum X_n^2$ converges almost surely.

Denote $\{B_n\}$ Bernoulli random variables, the statement above is to say $\sum B_n X_n$ converges a.s. implies $\sum X_n^2$ converges a.s.

Can anybody give a solution to this problem?

---

This problem comes from Kai Lai Chung's *A Course in Probability Theory*, Third Edition, pp.129

Comment: FYI, "the statement above" **is not saying that** $\sum B_n X_n$ converges a.s. implies $\sum X_n^2$ converges a.s.

Answer (score -1):

Since $\sum\limits_nB_nX_n<\infty$ $a.s.$, Thus $\exists K$ $s.t.$ $|B_nX_n|\le K$ $a.s.$

Notice that $E(B_nX_n)=EB_n\cdot EX_n=0$.

By Theorem 12.2 in *Probability with Martingales (Williams)*(Refer to  [The convergence of $\sum \pm a_n$ with random signs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1502681)) we obtain $\sum\limits_nVar(B_nX_n)<\infty$. (This may have some problems without the independence of $\{X_n\}$ as mentioned by the comments)

Thus $\sum\limits_nEX_n^2=\sum\limits_nE(B_nX_n)^2<\infty$.

Using Fubini's Theorem we have $E(\sum\limits_nX_n^2)<\infty$, therefore $\sum\limits_nX_n^2<\infty$ $a.s.$

Comment: The first line is $\sum a_n < \infty \to \lim a_n = 0 \to a_n \ \text{is convergent} \to a_n \ \text{is bounded}$ ?

Comment: How do you know 1. $\sum Var(B_n X_n) < \infty$? Do we have $Var(B_n X_n) < \infty$? 2. $E[B_n X_n] = E[B_n]E[X_n]$ ?

Comment: Dumb question: $\sum (a_n - b_n) < \infty \to \sum a_n < \infty$ and $ \sum b_n < \infty $?

Comment: No to the last, try for example $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = 1-1/2^n$

Comment: There are some problems with this answer. The first sentence is completely wrong. Plus, you can only use Theorem 12.2 if the random variables $(X_n)$ are independent, but is *not* assumed in the original post.

Comment: @BCLC  I think the first line is as the comment  you wrote. Since $\{B_n\}$ and $\{X_n\}$ are independent, we have $E(B_nX_n)=EB_n \cdot EX_n$. The convergence of the sum of the variation is by the Theorem in the Williams' book. I think the problem in the proof is that we don't have the independence of the $\{X_n\}$.

Comment: @cats thanks! ^-^

Comment: @ByronSchmuland why 'only' ? You can use if indp but also can use only if indp?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland The first line is because $\sum a_n < \infty \to \lim a_n = 0 \to a_n \ \text{is convergent} \to a_n \ \text{is bounded}$...?

Comment: @BCLC For more details, you can refer to Kai Lai Chung's A Course in Probability Theory, Third Edition, pp.129. Hope you can improve the solution.

Comment: @J.Mike ' $\{B_n\}$ and $\{X_n\}$ are independent' what exactly does this mean please?

Comment: @BCLC For any m and n, $B_m$ and $X_n$ are independent.