# Convergence of series of random variables with random signs.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $\{X_{n}, n\ge 1\}$ are arbitrary random variables such that $\sum_{n}\pm X_{n}$ converges almost surely for any choice of signs $\pm 1$.  Show that $\sum X_{n}^2<\infty$ almost surely. [Hint: Consider $\sum_{n} B_{n}(t)X_{n}(\omega)$ where the random variables $\{B_{n},n\ge 1\}$ are Bernoulli.  Apply Fubini on the space of $(t,\omega)$.]

**Remarks**

1. This is problem 7.7.4(b) of Resnick's A Probability Path.
2. We know that if $\sum \pm a_{i}$ converges almost surely, then $\sum a_{i}^2$ converges  if the $a_{i}$ are fixed (non-random).  This is discussed  [here, for example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502681/the-convergence-of-sum-pm-a-n-with-random-signs) It's also Lemma 7.6.1 of Resnick.
3. The point of the problem seems to be to pass from knowledge of the result for fixed values of the $X_{n}$ to random values; and presumably that's the point of the hint about Fubini.  But I don't understand exactly what's needed to draw this conclusion.

Comment: Note $\sum a_i^2$ converges almost surely if and only if $\sum a_i^2$ converges, because it isn't a random variable.  Maybe you realized this, but the phrase "$\sum a_i^2$ converges almost surely" is kind of weird when you realize you are talking about a fixed quantity.

Comment: You're right, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \{(t,w):\sum B_n(t) X_n(w)\}$ converges.  For each $w$, let $A_w = \{t : (t,w) \in A\}$, and for each $t$, let $A^t = \{w:(t,w) \in A\}$.

By hypothesis, for almost every $t$, the set $A^t$ has measure 1.  By Fubini, 
$$ \int \text{measure}(A_w) \, dw = \int \text{measure}(A^t) \, dt ,$$
since both sides equal $\int \!\!\int \chi_A(t,w) \, dt \, dw$.
Hence for almost every $w$, the set $A_w$ has measure 1.  But by your point 2, for any $w$, the set $A_w$ has measure 1 only if $\sum |X_n(w)|^2 < \infty$.

Thus for almost every $w$, we have $\sum |X_n(w)|^2 < \infty$.

Comment: Here I believe $A$ is a subset of the measure space $B\times X$ where $B$ is the countable product of copies of $\mathbf{R}$ with the discrete measure with mass $1/2$ at $-1$ and $1$ and $X$ is the countable product of $\mathbf{R}$ with Lebesgue measure; these countable products have the product measure.  Does Fubini hold in that generality?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to my previous question is clear because we are dealing with probability measures, so the spaces are $\sigma$-finite (actually finite) and therefore Fubini holds.

Comment: Also the space $\{\pm 1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is measure equivalent to $[0,1]$.  (Think about writing the numbers in base 2, or google "Radermacher functions.")